# How can I delete my profile / answers?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I would like to know how can I delete my profile , along with all my answers / comments or any other trace of my persona from this website .
I have tried sending a mail to the specified mail address - but no luck.
Even if it is ironic that the first question I ever ask on this site is how to disappear from here - Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Please follow [these instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/163749). If that is what you tried to do (I am not sure what email you refer to) and it didn't work let me know and I will delete your account personally.

Note that your contributions will likely be anonymized and retained, not deleted.

Sorry to see you go and best of luck.

PS also please clarify if [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/11035/obmer-kronen) is your account as well or is there reason you share IP and mostly upvote each other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . The e-mail address I am referring to is : team+wordpress@stackexchange.com .

Comment: Is there no way to delete all my answers and comments ? even going and deleting one by one ? as for the IP - I am not so sure for what reason would I need to clarify anything, and I am definitely not sure what you are insinuating or with whom exactly do I share IP - but If you insist knowing , I am frequently in china where many website are blocked/monitored/censured and almost all foreigners here use more or less the same proxy for safe access . if there is another user here from china - a shared IP might occur.

Comment: @krembo99 as far as I know by posting you are putting your content under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and in line with it site is under no obligation to let you retract submissions. This is not my personal opinion, I just relay how I was told such cases are handled. I thought I asked quite directly (no insinuating whatsoever) if that is your account as well. If you say it's not - good enough for me.

Comment: FWIW: We got your email, @krembo99 - but most of us were asleep at the time. Please be patient, we'll respond in due time.

Comment: @Shog9 - thank you. I just want to know about the issue of deleting the content before any further action. the CC-wiki license as intended (with attribution required) is regarding the content that I wrote .with anonymous content - no contribution to the author can be made.

Comment: @krembo99: The appropriate reference here is actually the Stack Exchange [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) (Section 3 -  Subscriber Content): by contributing to the site, you grant us a license to use your contributions, *even if* you later remove them. The CC BY-SA license is sort of stacked on this, and works to ensure that *we* don't abuse contributions (by, say, trying to prevent others from re-using them). If you request it, we will agree to remove your name from a post or from the site entirely - but mass-deletion is disruptive and will not be done.

Comment: @Shog9 thank you for the clarifications both here and in the thoughtful and more detailed mail regarding the other issues.I will further contemplate on future actions -  But I also think now you would need to invent a new "badge" for me to honor one of the greatest achievements of my life. Loosing more than 300 points and 2 badges in less than 24 hours is a record that I dare to say no one else can ever break on SE ! :-)

Comment: @krembo99: [lest you feel too bad about the lost rep...](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/#comment-45382)

Comment: @Shog9 - Couldn´t care less for those. It was a failed attempt to humor myself. the other issue though is rather annoying . Having a name, questions, and comments that are not mine  associated with me makes me wonder who is the poor someone it was "robbed" from. Because someone else inevitably wrote them .

Comment: @Shog9 :-) sorry, I just saw now that it was a link (screen contrast totally off)  .So I guess I will have to achieve something better in life . :-)